# How to positively identify file system errors on iOS

Tags: ios

I have a file open bug affecting a miniscule number of users (like .0002%) - and is unreproducible.

After it being reviewed over many months, I'd like to rule out memory and disk failures on the users device.

Some questions:

- Has anyone had experience with these errors on a device?
- What tools (programmatic or perhaps apps) could help identify these errors?
- In an iOS app, would it be common for an App to be the only app on the system to fail due to a bad disk?

(I would think due to sandboxing it might, but if I understand how modern SSDs work, I would expect the bad flash to be identified immediately and removed from use invisibly from the file system)

Any other help appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to add the details of the crash/bug.

Comment: iOS does employ wear levelling on its internal storage, so I would think that your assumption is correct that bad blocks should be taken out of service automagically.

Comment: I didn't want to waste anyones time engaging in the details as we are only looking at hardware diagnostics at this time, but here it is:

1. Files downloaded over http
2. Files observed in directory listing on device as expected
3. On first (or in some cases later) file open, NSFileReadUnknownError is returned for *some* files, (not alway the same ones).
4. Files are successfully deleted for re-download, and storage recovery is as expected for file sizes.
6. Happens to same users recurrently
8. Persists over multiple iOS versions, and app releases

Comment: Is the filename fixed, or may it for some reason include variable data (such as a username, book title...) that may somehow contain "weird" characters? Can the problem be isolated to specific devices? What APIs do you use to write and later read the files?

Comment: Does not contain unusual characters - even if it did, we're pulling the name from the directory listing, so should be fine. One user reports it happening on multiple devices, but I'm not ready to rule out device issue from one user report.